# No matching function for call to 'QuadBase::QuadBase'

Tags: c++, arduino

I just started learning C++ for an Arduino project me and a friend have been working on. I'm getting the error "No matching function for call to 'QuadBase::QuadBase'" in main.cpp. I'not sure what is causing it, since I have the correct amount of arguments and they are the same type as well

edit: I brought it down to this and it still gives me that same error

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "QuadBase.h"

QuadBase base;

void setup()
{

base = QuadBase(
        ...
    );
}
```

QuadBase.h

```
class QuadBase
{ public:
    QuadBase( ... )
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: You should work on a [mcve]. External links go bad, and it's not exactly reasonable to expect someone to dig through your repo to figure out your error. If the error is that you do not have a default constructor, perhaps that's the place to start.

Comment: Please improve your question

Comment: What type are `RobotMap::FRONT_LEFT_FOOT` etc. ? We don't know their definition. Also the error message will give you more details on _why_ there is no matching call.

Comment: RobotMap::FRONT_LEFT_FOOT etc. is defined in another h file that just stores integer values, even if I replaced those variables with regular integers I still get the same problem

Comment: @KhalilBalde Reducing the code to pseudo-code does not make answering it easier. There must be a type-mismatch or visibility issue somewhere in the code. You should reproduce a full compilable (but minimal) example code which still shows the error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your `class QuadBase` is missing a default constructor (one that takes no arguments) which is needed for the line

> ```
> QuadBase base;
> ```